# I accidentally killed all of my pulseaudio, now I have no sound.

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, restart

Ok I made a mistake. I was investigating on how to make it so that I could listen to music or watch videos when I wasn't using qjackctl after being connected to the computer. This is the youtube video I found jack and pulseaudio together as friends-linux. The problem that I ran into is he doesn't go into how to restart pulseaudio, he just says to do it. And so I did some more research on how and came up with this for the terminal:killall pulseaudio. Following this I typed pulseaudio  check. Now I no longer have a volume symbol in the top right of my computer and I cannot hear anything. Additionally, qjackctl and zyanaddsubfx no longer work. Please help, I appreciate all of your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the `pulseaudio` package will solve your problem of disappeared volume icon on the top panel.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

Comment: No luck yet. I have found that when I restarted the computer that it is visible, but after I type in my password it isn't. Earlier I thought maybe if I plugged in my MIDI connection that it might change things, which is how I found out about qjackctl and zynaddsubfx. It was still connected when I followed your instructions.

Comment: post the output of `sudo service pulseaudio status`

Comment: @ Avinash Raj- pulseaudio status:unrecognized service.

Comment: post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep pulseaudio`

Comment: @ Avinash Raj,per your request here is the response I get from the above code:brian@brian-NY550AA-ABA-p6240f:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep pulseaudio
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64   install
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64   install
pulseaudio     install
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth   install
pulseaudio-module-jack    install
pulseaudio-module-x11    install
pulseaudio-utils    install
brian@brian-NY550AA-ABA-p6240f:~$

Comment: and also post the output of `ls -l /etc/init.d/pulseaudio`

Comment: @ Avinash Raj thank you. I just got a message suggesting that we move to a chatroom. Here is the input from the code you told me to put in: rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2182 Sep 30  2013 /etc/init.d/pulseaudio

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14027/discussion-between-bjsgoodlife-and-avinash-raj)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu reinstalling the pulseaudio package solves his problem. First i think restarting the service will solves his problem, and then i come to know about this `pulseaudio status:unrecognized service` error.